# After ajax call when i click something page jump to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a ajax call for searching records. After the result come from ajax when I try to click on it the page jump to the top.

My function for ajax call:

```
 function ajax_search_primarycare(keyword, userId){
    if(keyword.length >= 3){
         var pricareId = jQuery('#primarycare_provider_id').val();
         var pricareName = jQuery('#primarycare_provider_name').val();
         var pricareStatus = jQuery('#primarycare_icon_status').val();
         var primary_badge_status = jQuery('#primary_badge_status').val();

     $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_search_primarycareprovider.php?keyword="+keyword+"&userId="+userId+"&pricareId="+pricareId+"&pricareName="+pricareName+"&pricareStatus="+pricareStatus+"&primary_badge_status="+primary_badge_status,
            success: function(msg){

            $("#sect_primarycare").html(msg);
            }
        });
return false;
    }
```

I have added return false after ajax call but still no result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can u show the html coming as ajax response

Comment: When you click *what*?  When is `ajax_search_primarycare` called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably jump to the top because a link to "#" is followed? Probably have an eventhandler attached to an  anchor element tag links to "#". When the event handler is done the default action is executed  (the link to #) unless the event handler returns false. 
Your Ajax-call returns false already but this is probably not the eventhandler? 
Solution is the make sure the actual event handler returns false.

To illustrate the point: user2675751 proposes the right solution indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes (and i don't know when, but i have observed same behavior on some of my scripts) `return false;` isn't enough.
You can try to add `javascript:void(0);` on your `href`
This works for me always.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning false on wrong place!

the result of the `ajax_search_primarycare` function is false, so lets say you call this function by something like this

```
$("#subbmit").click(function() {
   ajax_search_primarycare('k',1);
});
```

you have to return false with this function

```
$("#subbmit").click(function() {
   return ajax_search_primarycare('k',1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change your success callback to this :

```
success: function(msg){
    $("#sect_primarycare").html(msg);    
    $("#sect_primarycare").find('a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```